# Create/configure node.js dispatcher/proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I'm working on javascript Single Page Application with Aurelia framework and using simple fake backend(express.js) for prototyping purposes.
Backend runs on localhost:8081 and client app on localhost:9000
There are some Cross Domain issues because these are different ports, and adding cross origin headers to the backend seems cumbersome to me.

What i want is simple dispatcher/proxy that would run on, say, localhost:3000 and redirect incoming calls in this manner (localhost:3000/app => localhost:9000) (localhost:3000/api => localhost:8081) Thus eliminating cross domain issues.

I'm looking for really simple solution, maybe there is some node.js app that suited just for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express, you can add this routes to your app.

You need to install the module 'request' for this example

```
// At the top
var request = require('request');
```

And then:

```
//APP
app.use('/app', function (req, res) { request('http://localhost:9000' + req.originalUrl).pipe(res); });

//API
app.use('/api', function (req, res) { request('http://localhost:8081' + req.originalUrl).pipe(res); });
```